# How to Make Pop-Up Title Card on Hover?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table, thumbnails

So for my website, I have a portfolio page and I want to design a simple image thumbnail for my Google doc or Word documents to link essays and stuff. The same for PDFs, Slides, etc.

I want the logo or letter to be shown and when you hover on it, I want a title card to "pop" up and like bounce up a bit and then when you hover  off, I want the card to slide down and disappear.

In theory, this is what I want it to look like:
[image: Thumbnail]

Whether it just slides up and then slides down or shoots up, bounces like it's hitting the bottom of the square, then falls down, doesn't matter - I'm just wondering how to do this.

Comment: Edit your post and show your code please

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You've described what you want, but you haven't identified a problem to solve. Please read about [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a ton of different ways to do this.

Here is a CSS only way.

Basically, you would create a different class name for each title card that you want to have a hover pop-up caption. I use a pseudo selector for the content in the hover pop up.

Hope this helps!

```css
.title-card {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 5px;
  background: #e8e8e8;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.38);
  border-radius: 6px;
  color: black;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

.title-card::before {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0.53) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.24) 100%); 
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0.53) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.24) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0.53) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.24) 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#87000000', endColorstr='#3d000000',GradientType=0 );
  color: #fff;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(200%);
  transition: all 500ms ease;
}

.title-card:hover::before {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(100%);
}

.title-card.caption-a::before {
  content: "Hello from the other side!";
}

.title-card.caption-b::before {
  content: "It's tricky!";
}

.title-card.caption-c::before {
  content: "Don't call it a comeback!";
}

.title-card.logo-a {
 background-image: url(https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-icon.png?v=c78bd457575a);
}

.title-card.logo-b {
 background-image: url(https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/se/se-icon.png?v=93426798a1d4);
}

.title-card.logo-c {
 background-image: url(https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/sf/sf-icon.png?v=6c3100d858bb);
}

.title-card.logo-d {
 background-image: url(https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/su/su-icon.png?v=0ad5b7a83e49);
}
```

```html
<div class="title-card logo-a caption-a">I have a caption, hover over me!</div>
<div class="title-card logo-b caption-b">I have a caption, hover over me!</div>
<div class="title-card logo-c caption-c">I have a caption, hover over me!</div>
<div class="title-card logo-d">I don't have a hover caption :(</div>
```